# Paypal access token expires every 1 hour

Tags: php, api, paypal

How do I make it not expire? or atleast what's the workaround for this?

Right now I am getting the access token using Postman. It works well until it expires.

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you googled anything?

Comment: _It works well until it expires...._ This is the life of tokens...and the reason why they exist

Comment: You don't.  It's deliberately designed that way.  It's up to you to get your code to handle the case where the token you have has expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check if its expired, if so make a new API-call to get a new one/refresh it?